# Cannot match exclusion of a character in Regular Expression when url Rewriting

Tags: c#, regex, url-rewriting

I'm trying to match all urls that have courses/wwwwddd and nothing after the dd. (or at least no / characters after.

My expression is:

```
(.*)courses\/(\w{4}\d{3})[^/]
```

But it does not work at all.

I know the trouble is from [^/] .

I search the stackoverflow, I tried so many things and I could not get any results.

I would appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: you should test your regexes before searching for help, I like using this online tool; http://regexpal.com/ it doesn't apply to all languages, but it helps a lot ;)

Comment: I've already done that. I use http://gskinner.com/RegExr which is a flash regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a negative lookahead:

```
(.*)courses\/(\w{4}\d{3})(?!\/)
```

This ensures that there are no slashes after the last digit. I'm not sure why you escaped the other slash, but I followed your example there. It's likely you don't need either of those backslashes, though.